# Rails: maintaining application-dependent data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, data-migration

In my application an `account` has various unique messages (`message_templates`) they need to display to users.  For instance, in one account when a new post is created, they may way to display "Thanks for creating the post!" and another account may want to say "The post was successfully created!".

There are a set number of these in-app `message_templates` that only get triggered at certain times.  Thus, each account will have the same number, just differing values.

```
account = Account.create!
MessageTemplate.create(account: account, slug: "post_created_thank_you", body: "Thank you for creating the post!")
...
# Can change the body column but nothing else.

def PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # create the post...
    @thank_you_message = current_account.message_templates.find_by(
      slug: "post_created_thank_you"
    )
  end
end
```

As I'm adding features to the application, however, I find that sometimes I want to add another `message_template` and I need to ensure this template is created for all the current accounts.

I was thinking about using Rails migrations to ensure each `account` had the various `message_templates` but migrations are really for DB schema changes and not for application data changes.

I also looked at `rake db:seed`, but this is really for seeding the DB initially, not for maintaining updates.

One solution is creating rake tasks that I manually execute whenever I add a new templated message.  Seems a bit clunky.

What I would really like is migrations built for data.  This seems like a common issue, is there a standard way of implementing this?  Otherwise I'll probably end up writing a gem that implements migrations for data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create data in migration the same way you'd do in a seed file eg:

```
def up
   Account.each do |account|
     MessageTemplate.create(account: account, slug: "post_created_thank_you", body: "Thank you for creating the post!")
  end
end
def down
  MessageTemplate.where(slug: "post_created_thank_you").delete_all
end
```

Or a better idea is to turn the above into a SQL insert so it runs quicker...

Comment: I know I can put data into the migrations themselves, but I hear a lot of folks recommend not doing that: migrations now have business logic in them (ie, data) and you can't remove/squash those migrations without breaking core app functionality.  I'm toying with doing exactly what you recommended, but I wanted to see if there is a cleaner approach first.

Comment: No matter what you do, you're still going to have data... and it will still need to be run in a migration to get it into your prod db. Any other solution is just an obfuscation of that fact. There are other ways of slicing the cake... but they all boil down to "i run a migration and it runs something that puts data in the db" :)